# Coalesce sort in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am looking to sort my Customers collection by the following

```
{
 lastName: 1,
 firstName:1,
 companyName:1
}
```

But, I want blanks to be ignored. Essentially it'd be like sorting on a `field === lastName + firstName + companyName`

This can be achieved by coalesce in [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Anyone know how to achieve this without using the aggregation framework (Meteor app)?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's a way without just storing a extra field with the fields combined in the way you want them.

Comment: As @WiredPrairie suggested, storing an explicit `sort` field would be the only way to achieve your outcome without using the Aggregation Framework.  You *could* wrangle a result with Aggregation and a `$project` pipeline with `$concat`, but this would be much less performant than just adding an explicit field.